# Listen for button click inside WebView and implement certain logic behind it

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm showing a `WebView` inside my application. `WebView` contains a `"Return"` button. I want to listen for this button click and finish the `activity A` and open `activity B` if this happens.

To achieve this, I've come up with two solutions:

A) Add `WebViewClient` listener and just execute my logic on `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` callback.

B) Use `Deep Links`

Which of these two solutions are **more correct** and **why**? I think deep links are usually used when you want to go from *other mobile app* to *X destination* *in your* app and not other way around. Am I mistaken something here?

Answer (score 0):

As i know you have to use `deep` `link` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` use for :

> If a WebViewClient is not provided, by default WebView will ask
> Activity Manager to choose the proper handler for the URL

In the other hands we can handle some situation when we open a web view in
`shouldOverrideUrlLoading` `fun` :

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
        val url = request.url.toString()
            if (url.startsWith("intent://")) {
                try {
                    val intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)
                    startActivity(intent)
                } catch (error: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    return false
                }
                return true
            }
        return false
    }
}
```

Then in your situation :

> I want to listen for this button click and finish the activity A and
> open activity B if this happens.

You have to use `deep` `link` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`:

> When a clicked link or programmatic request invokes a web URI intent,
> the Android system tries each of the following actions, in sequential
> order, until the request succeeds:
>
> -Open the user's preferred app that can handle the URI, if one is designated.
>
> -Open the only available app that can handle the URI.
>
> -Allow the user to select an app from a dialog.